# How does the paring of indices work in matrices?

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, mathematics, matrix-elements

I am not sure whether the title does convey what I want to ask, but here are two observations from the cited (freely available) articles:

1. Below equation 1 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.05122), a matrix $T_{ijkl}$ with four indices $i,j,k,l$ is redefined as $U_{ij,kl} := T_{ijkl}$.
2. Below equation 4 (in the statement of Theorem) of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01601), matrix $M_{ijk}$ is used to define another matrix $M_{j,ik}$.

My question: What do the matrices $U_{ij, kl}$ and $M_{j,ik}$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a different way to label the entries of the "matrix" $T_{ijkl}$.

Suppose for example $i,j,k,l$ run from 1 to N, then  $T_{ijkl}$ has $N^4$ entries. You can think of the pair $i,j$ as a single 'doubled' index that runs from 1 to $N^2$ (corresponding to the $N^2$ possible values that the pair $i,j$ can have),
and then rewrite $T_{ijkl}$ as a $N^2$-by-$N^2$ matrix $U_{ij,kl}$.

Note: commas can be used to denote derivatives in differential geometry and general relativity, but this is not the case here.

Comment: That makes sense! Could you suggest some reference/s where this notion is formalized?

Comment: I don't know if there is really any formal definition for this notation since this is quite straightforward. You might see something similar in the way the entries of a Kronecker product are indexed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product